# Possible short story about a psychically bonded human-alien society? (Not Romance)

Tags: aliens, psychic, story-identification

From what I remember the story is about a girl and her alien partner who are being trained in a school (in space?) for alien/human bonded pairs.

They share a strong psychic connection and they have contrasting personalities.

They might be trained to either be peacekeepers or for war/protection purposes (not sure).

In the story, they talk about past missions in which they saved something and now the government is thankful to them ( which makes me believe it might be a series??)

Sadly that's all I remember. The focal point to me at the time was the bond between the two. I might have read it in a middle school textbook in the  2000s? Might be the same textbook I read “The Smallest Dragonboy” by Anne McCaffrey. But that's just going off the time period...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know if you're still looking for the answer to this question, but I believe the short story you're looking for is "[The Real Thing](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?944313)" by Alison Goodman. The story focuses on the slightly genetically enhanced Joss Aaronson and her psychically-bonded alien partner Mavkel. It was included in the short story anthology *[Firebirds Rising](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?180980)*, edited by Sharyn November. There's just one novel telling the beginning of Joss and Mavkel's story called *[Singing the Dog Star Blues](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?21450)*. From what I remember, it was a fast-paced and very enjoyable read, and refreshingly free of romance for a book with a teen protagonist.

I hope this helps. Happy reading! :)

Comment: Thank you so very much! This looks to be exactly what I was looking for! I was beginning to think that I had dreamed the whole thing. Thanks!